# How to print files using the Android's Default Print Service?

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm on Android Oreo which is version 8. This has introduced a way to no longer need any services outside of the Android OS and instead [use its "Default Printing Service"](https://9to5google.com/2017/08/22/android-8-0-oreos-default-print-service/) for printing with an Android phone. These outside services include *Google's Cloud Print, HP, Canon, Xerox, & several others.* Besides those services, you may stick with the built-in one provided by Android itself and it's called "Default Print Service by Android", and in order to begin using it, you'll first have to enable it if not done so already. To do this, go to Settings -> Advanced -> Printing -> Select it, then enable. Now, what it'll do is search for the printers in your network and you know this by what WiFi you're on using your phone.

The problem is, after the list refreshes, you can't go any further. It just let you know: *these are the printers in your network and nothing more.* I see the printer I'm going to use to print to, but unable to do anything more than to identify that it's in my network by displaying an IP underneath it. So, I did [online research with those responsible](https://mopria.org/android-8-9-faq#collapse1) and that didn't help because there's no instructions as to how to print. So then, I'm left with a recognized printer not being able to have the option to print or at least show me how to get to the option to print.

My question is **how do you print from Android using the Default Print Service besides just using it as a tool to view printers in your network?**

## PROBLEM

- Android's "Default Print Service" only shows printers but is unable to choose a printer for printing

  - An example of me printing is viewing a PDF document and for Android, you have to either find the following options when viewing a file via cogwheel/3-button icon:

    - *Share...*
    - *Send To...*
    - *Open With...*
  - At this point I don't see "Default Print Service" as a selection and this is the problem

## SOLUTION

- None-so-far

##### NOTE

- Finding "Default Print Service" in Android may vary with different phones

  - Location: Settings -> Advanced -> Printing
- Files can be images to anything with text like a PDF or even a txt file

Comment: Thanks for writing down this question and background.  I am stuck at the same place.  Based on [this forum](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/697187/inability-to-print-through-default-print-service/), my best guess is that the default print service only enables apps to print, but most apps just don't interface with it yet.  Other apps I have used (like RepliGo PDF reader) seem to only work with Google Cloud Print.

Comment: What are you trying to print and which app are you trying to print from? At present it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In apps that support this type of printing, e.g. [Simple Gallery Pro | F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.gallery.pro/) you can simply choose print from the menu and you are taken to a print preview that interfaces with the Default Print Service. Here you can choose which of your printers to use and adjust paper size etc and finally send the job off to print.

Answer (score 0):

> how do [I] print from Android using the Default Print Service besides just using it as a tool to view printers in your network?

Short answer:
You can't without an application that has print capabilities, because you can't connect directly to the service to do anything aside from configuration.

Longer answer:
You are confusing a **system service** with a **user application**.

Basic rule:

- A **service provides the *ability* to do something** like Bluetooth, internet, WiFi, phone calls, etc.
- An **application provides the *way*** for a user to ***use*** a particular service.

For example:

- The network **service** provides apps the ability to connect to the internet.
- A web browser is an **application** that uses the network service to get a connection to the internet.

To print something, you need two things:

1. A configured service that is attached to your printer, (which you already appear to have).
2. An application that can use the service to print something.  For example: Libre Office, Photos, a text editor, etc. that has the ability to print.